# Dismissing a viewController resets presenting navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a UINavigation controller. The viewController contents is as follows

```
[RestaurantViewController, MenuViewController, ProductViewController]
```

In ProductViewController I call

```
self.navigationController?.present(sideViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

This presents the view controller as expected. Now when I call self.dismiss/self.presentingViewController.dismiss from within sideViewController, the original NavigationController Resets to

```
[RestaurantViewController]
```

Why is this? I just want to dismiss and be returned to the presenting viewController

Comment: Test in a small clean project and you will see that the behavior you describe is not normal. Therefore you are doing something else that causes the navigation controller to pop/unwind back to the RestaurantViewController. But you have not described what that is; only you can find out.

Comment: The problem must lie in what happens after controller is dismissed. You must have called `popToRootViewController` some where or you are using someone's library that calls this `popToRootViewController`

Comment: @matt You were right, I was calling some code that declared viewControllers being called inside a viewWillAppear function rather than a viewDidLoad therefore was resetting it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just present the controller from ProductViewController using

```
self.present(sideViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Then dismiss using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
```

Other than that there could be many things that could cause your issues.  If you want a navigation controller on the sideViewController then create a navigation controller and set sideViewController as the rootviewcontroller and present the navigation controller.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: //SideViewController)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```